# Inserting data from a join within tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to figure out how to extend a table of company_ids using a group reference from another table.  For a given company_name, I want to get its company_ids, join them with the company_groups table, and get their group_ids.  From there, I want to get every company_id associated with the group_id, and insert them in the companies table with the proper company_name.

The structure is a bit atypical.  A single company name can have many IDs, because the ID isn't used as a unique identifier for a single company.  I'm trying to make sure all of them get copied to the companies table.  I'm sure there's a fairly simple join command, but I've never been very good at joining tables within themselves.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

```
+---------------+
|   companies   |
+---------------+
| company_id PK |
| company_name  |
+---------------+

+----------------+
| company_groups |
+----------------+
| company_id PK  |
| group_id       |
+----------------+
```

Here's an example.  In the companies table, I have the company "Tesla", with three different IDs.

```
+--------------+------------+
| company_name | company_id |
+--------------+------------+
| Tesla        |     647552 |
| Tesla        |     927572 |
| Tesla        |     748563 |
+--------------+------------+
```

In the company_groups table, each group_id has one or more company_ids.

```
+----------+------------+
| group_id | company_id |
+----------+------------+
| 227      |     647552 |
| 227      |     111743 |
| 227      |     111842 |
+----------+------------+
```

I want to match the company_name to multiple group_ids, then find all company_ids associated with the group.  The new company_ids would then be inserted in the companies table like this:

```
+--------------+------------+
| company_name | company_id |
+--------------+------------+
| Tesla        |     647552 |
| Tesla        |     927572 |
| Tesla        |     748563 |
| Tesla        |     111743 |
| Tesla        |     111842 |
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: In your companies table you have one company with several company_Id? Can you update your question and put a sample of whatt you mean. Not just the description of the tables.

Comment: I added an example.  Hopefully it will be a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  A nested query works well:

```
REPLACE INTO companies (company_name, company_id)
SELECT a.company_name, company_groups.company_id
FROM
(
SELECT group_id, company_groups.company_id, companies.company_name
FROM companies
JOIN company_groups
ON companies.company_id=company_groups.company_id
GROUP BY group_id
) a
JOIN company_groups
ON company_groups.group_id=a.group_id
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into a table when the same table name appear in the where clause.

You can use a temporary third table to do this job

At second thought, your question is either funny or not clear enough, please provide your sample data, so that i can update my answer